# How can you forward long headers in Apple Mail 8.1 using Yosemite (needed when reporting suspected fraud)

Tags: mail.app

also wondering if any way to have a return of incoming mail being individually numbered as existed in mail used with 10.6.8

Comment: Where do you want the numbers to be? Next to each incoming message? I'm not aware of such a setting.

Comment: Could you split these out into two separate questions. Otherwise they become un-Googleable for future seekers.

Answer (score 4):

To forward with all headers intact, for phishing/fraud reporting etc, use
Message > Forward as Attachment.

[image]

Comment: that's not headers intact, that's placing all headers in another envelope.

Comment: which gets them to the destination… intact. I'm not sure what your point is.

Answer (score 0):

In Mail go to the View menu, and choose Customize Toolbar. In the toolbar customization interface, drag the button for “Show (or hide) all headers” to the toolbar. It has a small magnifying glass and a little piece of mail on it. Then just click on that anytime you want to reveal a long header.

Comment: that's show, not forward. In all previous versions of Mail, if you were showing headers and clicked Forward it would forward the headers. This was removed in Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

Select View → Message → Raw Source (<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>). This will display the full message (all headers included) in plain text as is received by the mail server.

Comment: that's show, not forward.